# Altium Designer - How to copy the parameters from one component in the SCH Library to another component

Tags: altium

For context, I am using a component from Altium's Vault Explorer and I want to make a few edits to it. Thus I downloaded the component SCH, but the parameters did not copy over.

Is there an easy method to copy the parameters from a Vault Explorer component and paste them into a component in the SCH Library?

Comment: I don't use vault, but did you try placing the component on a schematic then copying it?

Comment: I can do that, but I want the component in the SCH Library to contain the parameter information, so that if I or someone else places a new component, that new component will contain the parameter information.

Comment: If you copy the component from a schematic **into a library** it should retain the parameter information.

Comment: Woah that worked! I didn't even know you could do that. Thank you @Spehro! :D

Comment: I'll make it an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert the component into any schematic, copy it, then open the target library SCH and paste the part in. All the parameters will be preserved.

Comment: Oops I just finished writing an answer. Should I leave the answer or delete it?

Comment: Leave it and I'll up-vote- you added some detail like the ?.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Spehro for answering the question in the comments.

To copy the parameters from a Vault Explorer component into your SCH Library:

1. Place the Vault Explorer component onto your schematic.
2. Copy the component (ctrl+c)
3. Paste the component into your SCH Library (ctrl+v)
4. Double-click on the pasted component in SCH Library. "Library Component Properties" window should pop up
5. Under "Properties" in the "Default Designator" box replace the number with a "?"

You should now be able to use the component normally.